# AngularJS links don't open in Visual Studio Simulator

Tags: angularjs, cordova, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to build a Windows app for Surface pro 3 using Phonegap . I am using AngularJS to build this app. The app works fine when i open it in browser, but when i try to open the app in the Visual Studio simulator, the navigation links don't work. Following message pops up whenever i click on a link:

No apps are installed to open this kind of link(unsafe).

Can anyone please help me ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to fix the URL prefixes. See this post:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msdn_answers/archive/2015/02/10/running-cordova-apps-on-windows-and-windows-phone-8-1-using-ionic-angularjs-and-other-frameworks.aspx